# Haxe lua.Table<String, Int>: String should be Int

Tags: types, lua, casting, typeerror, haxe

My problem is that haxe doesn't want to compile a following snippet to lua target. It complains about:
`Main.hx:7: characters 11-17 : String should be Int`

```
import lua.Table;

class Main {
    static public function my_test(): Table<String, Int>
    {
        var t: Table<String, Int> = Table.create();
        t["test"] = 1; # Heres the problem
        return t;
    }

    static public function main(): Void
    {
        var x = my_test();
        trace(x);
    }
}
```

If I change the problematic line to:
`t[1] = 1;` It strangely doesn't complain which seems not logical to me as it's a wrong type in my understanding.

If I put `$type(t)` somewhere into the snippet above, it correctly identifies it as `lua.Table<String, Int>`.

I looked into source of `std/lua/Table.hx` and based on some code there I used `untyped` keyword in my snippet: `t[untyped "test"] = 1;` only then it generates desired lua code that executes successfully:

```
Main.my_test = function()
  local t = ({});
  t.test = 1;
  do return t end;
end
```

Although I expected something like:

```
Main.my_test = function()
  local t = {};
  t["test"] = 1;
  do return t end;
end
```

So, why I have to use this keyword?

```
$ haxe --version
4.2.1+bf9ff69

# I compile with
$ haxe -D lua-vanilla --main Main --lua Main.lua
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of Haxe and how the external library is defined as an `extern` instead of wrapped in an abstract. In [std/lua/Table.hx](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/bf9ff69c0801082174f0b2b0a66faeb5356de580/std/lua/Table.hx), `Table<A, B>` is defined as implementing [`ArrayAccess<B>`](https://api.haxe.org/ArrayAccess.html). This tells Haxe that the type supports indexing into it with integers and that the element type is `B`. There is no way for it to indicate that the allowed indexer type is `A`. [`ArrayAccess<T>`](https://api.haxe.org/ArrayAccess.html)’s documentation states:

> This interface should be used for externs only. Haxe does not support custom array access on classes. However, array access can be implemented for abstract types.
>
> https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html

Instead of defining `lua.Table` as a simple `extern` in this way, you might be able to define a wrapper around it as an abstract. That would let you specify an array setter/getter appropriately. An example of doing this is below.:

```
extern class LuaGTable<A, B> implements ArrayAccess<B> {
}

abstract MyLuaTable<K, V>(LuaGTable<K, V>) {
  inline public function new() {
    this = untyped __lua__("({})");
  }
  @:arrayAccess
  public inline function set(k: K, v) {
    this[untyped k] = v;
  }
  @:arrayAccess
  public inline function get(k: K) {
        return this[untyped k];
  }
}
```

The use of `implements ArrayAccess<B>` is required to permit use of the indexing operator in the expression `this[untyped k]` at all. What Haxe thinks we’re doing is supplying an integer value to the indexing expression. The abstract itself provides the `K`/`V`-typed indexer.

Why this isn’t the approach taken by the Haxe standard library is something I do not know. You could probably find or file a bug at their GitHub repository to start a discussion on this. I don’t think making `Table<A, B>` hard to use was intentional.